# iPhone html 5 video asp.net IIS

Tags: iphone, asp.net, iis, html5-video

I have a video element on a page which has an mp4, ogg, and fallback flash inside it. On IE9, the html5 video works fine, but on an iPhone, the video doesn't play. I've set up the mimetypes in the web.config (root) and in IIS on the site level and server level... I don't see why it's not working... We recently moved the site to a new server and I think it was working on the iPhone on the old server. Any ideas?

**Update**
I forgot to mention that I've tried playing the same video file through dropbox and it works fine. I'm not sure if the HTML 5 video tag on iPhone requires a more specific format for the MP4 but if the video plays "offline" shouldn't it play in the video tag? So for that reason I don't think it's an encoding problem. The source code hasn't changed. So I'm thinking it's an IIS thing...

**Update**

Here's the source code:

```
<video controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" width="640" height="360">
    <source src="https://www.MyWebsiteName.com/Images/movies/MyMovieName.mp4" Type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="https://www.MyWebsiteName.com/Images/movies/MyMovieName.ogg" Type="video/ogg" />
    <object width="640" height="360" id="movie_name" align="middle">
        <param name="movie" value="../Images/movies/MyMovieName.swf" />
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="../Images/movies/MyMovieName.swf" width="320" height="180">
            <param name="movie" value="movie_name.swf" />
        <!--<![endif]-->
            Please upgrade your web browser. <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie/home">Click here</a>
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
        <!--<![endif]-->
    </object>
</video>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend attaching a web debugger to the iPhone. You can then intercept the request that it made, and from there you will be able to verify the response from the web server.

It is possible that it is just not receiving the correct video element.

Comment: I tried the debug console, but nothing. Please see my update in the question too. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have an example which I can look at?